# pylint reports => test.py:32:8: W0104: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)

Tags: python, pylint

This code I wrote for a school assignment. I checked the code with pylint, and pylint reports pointless-statement for all if elif else statements. I don't know how to improve my code, is there someone who could help me out? Thanks

```
USD = 0.8500
GBP = 1.1700
JPY = 0.0077
RATE = 0.015
FEE_MIN = 2.00
FEE_MAX = 15.00

choise = int(input("Which currency do you want to exchange for euros? "
                   "1) USD dollar,2) GB pound, 3) JP yen : "))

#USD
if (choise) == 1:
    foreign = round(float(input("What amount of dollars do you want to convert"
                                " to euros? : ")))
    euros = round((foreign * USD), 2)
    COST = (round((foreign * USD), 2) * RATE)
    if COST <= FEE_MIN:
        COST = FEE_MIN
    elif COST > FEE_MAX:
        COST = FEE_MAX
    else:
        COST
    payout = (float(euros) - float(COST))
    print("The transactioncost are: {:.2f}.".format(COST))
    print("You'll receive {:.2f} euros.".format(payout))
#GBP
if (choise) == 2:
    foreign = round(float(input("What amount of pounds do you want to convert"
                                " to euros? : ")))
    euros = round((foreign * GBP), 2)
    COST = (round((foreign * GBP), 2) * RATE)
    if COST <= FEE_MIN:
        COST = FEE_MIN
    elif COST > FEE_MAX:
        COST = FEE_MAX
    else:
        COST
    payout = (float(euros) - float(COST))
    print("The transactioncost are: {:.2f}.".format(COST))
    print("You'll receive {:.2f} euros.".format(payout))
#JPY
if (choise) == 3:
    foreign = round(float(input("What amount of yen's do you want to convert"
                                " to euros? : ")))
    euros = round((foreign * JPY), 2)
    COST = (round((foreign * JPY), 2) * RATE)
    if COST <= FEE_MIN:
        COST = FEE_MIN
    elif COST > FEE_MAX:
        COST = FEE_MAX
    else:
        COST
    payout = (float(euros) - float(COST))
    print("The transactioncost are: {:.2f}.".format(COST))
    print("You'll receive {:.2f} euros.".format(payout))
```

Comment: For the exchange, the customer has to pay transaction costs. These amount to 1.5%, with a minimum of 2 euros per transaction and a maximum of 15 euros per transaction. This is what I tried to solve this way.

Comment: Seems i've misread that. Its probably hinting that `COST` in the else's doesn't do anything.

Comment: `else: COST` is pointless. It might as well be `else: pass`.  It is legal to have an expression as a statement, but the two main reasons to do this are docstrings and when the expression is a function call with a side effect like `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
    else:
        COST
```

Does nothing.